# When using a virtual machine scale set, how do you view the CPU utilization of a VM in the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm using a load balancer with a VMSS which I've created using the Azure template 201-vmss-windows-autoscale.

How do I view the CPU utilization of each of the VMs running in the VMSS?

ps this is NOT about autoscaling based on CPU utilization.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we are not able to check the metrics such as CPU utilization of VMs running in VMSS on the portal directly.

As a workaround, you may use some application to log these metric inside of the VM. Then you are able to retrieve the log for analysis.

For Linux OS, you may write a script to log it.

For Windows OS, there is a built-in tool called performance counter.

Answer (score 0):

CPU and other metrics for VM scale sets are being integrated directly into the portal. This feature started rolling out in the last couple of weeks and you'll start to see it for all scale sets when you look at the scale set properties. The data is represented as an aggregate, i.e. average CPU consumption for VMs. You can also configure alerts for when metrics like CPU usage exceeds values you set. As well as integrated metrics you can also click on the "Metrics" portal option to choose which resources to look at. There is also an API to go with it.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt743622.aspx .

If you want CPU data for individual VMs, the diagnostic extension is a good method. For Windows this is called the Windows Diagnostic Extension (also known as WAD (Windows Azure Diagnostics). The template you referred to in your question installs this extension, and individual VMs send metrics data to tables in a storage account that is created by the template. You can query the data in this storage account directly using an Azure storage explorer, Visual Studio, or with the Azure storage tables API. For information about what these tables look like take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-troubleshoot/ - although the article is about autoscale, the diagnostics is relevant to any scale set which has the diagnostic extension installed.

Comment: I have seen the graph in the portal for the vmss. It looked promising. Then I compared it to the CPU that the VM reports in Performance counters and it was completely different!. Only one VM so no issue with it being an averaging issue.

Comment: Can you check this again in about a week. There was an issue with data going to the graph reported last week and it's being fixed.